# Introducing a stochastic superoptimizer for retro CPUs

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I'm writing to introduce my software project [strop](https://github.com/omarandlorraine/strop). Like a compiler, it takes a function as input, and it emits assembly language that computes the given function. But unlike a compiler, the way it generates the function is by a bruteforce search, or by a random search.

Currently, strop has mostly targetted CPUs for which [C is a bad fit](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/why-do-c-to-z80-compilers-produce-poor-code), and which mainstream compilers (e.g. GCC, LLVM, MSVC, ...) don't have mainline support for, which will obviously include some of the CPUs that are on-topic here, such as:

- a few different varieties of 6502,
- Z80 (static analysis can exclude instructions that the Intel 8080 won't accept)
- ARMv4 (for example, the ARM7TDMI)

Strop has not really been put through its paces yet. But I believe this kind of technology is of interest to some people, some of which will be found here, so feel free to take a look.

If you have any questions, feel free to post something here, or file an issue on github or something.

Comment: Interesting. Quite opposite to my usual field of work. Also remarkable what can be done with seemingly unlimited computing power :)) I like that. I wish I had more time to dive into.